# Exporting CSV keeps printing HTML page

Tags: php, html, csv

I'm trying to print this simple line of code to understand what is the issue but it prints out entire HTML code instead absolutely ignoring the small array

```
$list = array(
    "Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway",
    "Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway",
);
$file = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($list as $line) {
    fputcsv($file, explode(',', $line));
}
fclose($file);

header("Content-Type: application/text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SDS.csv")
```

I have no idea why it keeps doing it or how to prevent it.

Comment: Put the headers and content type first

Comment: Same result whenever i put it above the snippet i sent here or above any code on main page.

Comment: What does the page around the snippet look like? Is it a whole web page? Then there could be two problems - one on hand a single HTTP request can either deliver a webpage or the CSV file, not both. And if you see the PHP code you may be missing <?php and ?> around the code itself - or the server may not have been configured to process the file as PHP

Comment: I apologize as my understanding in these terms is a bit limited but I'm fairly sure it's configured properly, there's no missing <?php ?>, and request is singlar? I'm not sure what you mean how it looks like? It's a page with buttons and other things in it. If I put header codes above the snippet practically every button i click starts to download the csv with html code in it, if the header is below it only does when i click on appropriate button, but HTML code in csv remains either way...

Comment: Is the codesnippet you posted above kept inside the same document as your webpage? If so - do you distinguish the requests by any request parameters so that you deliver only the page on the first request and only the CSV on the second request to the server? It would be great if you could edit the question to show a little bit more around the current code snipped (where does PHP start, etc.).

Comment: It is the same page, distinguished by different $_POST name. The full snippet lacks if ($_POST["sendExcel"]) { ... snippet i sent earlire ... } basically do only this on the click of the input type=submit

Comment: I've updated my answer with a longer code sample - does the code look something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write headers (Content-type, Cookies, etc.) before any other output is written. If you write headers after content they are silently discarded.

In some cases writing the headers after content may seem to work when output buffering is enabled and the buffer has not been flushed to the client already.

**EDIT**: As has been discovered in comments above the code may not work because the webpage seems to have been outputed directly in front of the CSV data. In this case one has to split the request for the webpage and for the CSV into two parts. One could for example use an GET/POST parameter (depending on the semantics) to distinguish what should be returned or use PATH_INFO (if the server is configured that way).

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['format']) && ($_GET['format'] == "csv")) {
  header("Content-Type: application/text");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SDS.csv");

  $list = array(
    "Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway",
    "Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway",
  );
  $file = fopen("php://output", "w");
  foreach ($list as $line) {
    fputcsv($file, explode(',', $line));
  }
  fclose($file);

  /*
    Now terminate processing of the script so following HTML
    is not written.
  */
  return;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> CSV example </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p> Download <a href="example?format=csv">CSV</a> from here </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think i'm starting to understand, so first of all thank you for taking your time to explain, however seems like i'm still lacking something as from the example you provided it seems to still print out a part of HTML, but not all of it this time.

Comment: Do you print any HTML above the decision (i.e. above the if($_POST[...]))? If so, move that below the end of the code that outputs the CSV. (Try to think about the control flow during the requests - the control flow always starts at the top and as long as there is only HTML it outputs these characters; if it enounters PHP blocks it executes them in order as long as you don't use functions). You want to have two different control flows for CSV and HTML so the decision has to be made before any HTML and any CSV (in fact any output) is written

Comment: Alright I managed to print out following your suggestions, so it works, thank you! Now the only issue left is to have the same SQL i use to filter out the data to be somehow ported at the start of the main page before HTML even generates, problem is the SQL is generated on another page so I don't know if i should put it into a $_SESSION or something, however I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: You mean you decide which filters you use on another page? You can either put them into a session if it's really session specific or you could use a pattern like REST if there is a hierarchical query (like /reports/A /reports/B) - or use GET/POST parameters (dependent if the query does not change state (GET) or does (POST))

Comment: Basically what happens is I have SQL which prints out  ALL data initially on first load, after that user has accesso to several panels that are connected to specific tables to search by various criteria, when they choose what they want to search for via said filters they press "search" and SQL is once again called upon to retrieve all data but then depending on which POST the server gets, it adds few more lines that filter out specific data user requires. In the end I have long SQL that I need to put in a session so when user clicks on put to CSV the SQL with filter on prints specific data

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to build the request based on the selected filters (i.e. the GET/POST data from the form?). That would allow to design the HTTP interface in a database agnostic way. Of course if you collect data over various refinements of the search collecting the filter criteria (or the SQL) inside a session is a valid way of solving that problem - one could also build hidden form fields on every iteration though to have that thing stateless (client side storage in cookies would also be a possible solution)

Answer (score 0):

Same Code working fine with me.

You just need to make sure nothing is outputting before headers, even space also matter in this case.

Writing code before headers settings will not create any problem but outputting to browser will create problem.So just cross check once again.

Comment: There is a lot of content outputting before it, but I can't just not generate that content so i'm basically out of options then? It's simply not compatible with the website, i guess.

Comment: If something is outputting before then defiantly it will not work.